# How to set `tax_query` with `query->set()`

Tags: tax-query

While this works:

```
$query->set( 'post__not_in', array( 30140, 30020, 30008, 29998, 29991, 21458, 20197, 11986, 6614 ) );
```

This doesn't:

```
$tax_query = array(
  'taxonomy' => 'filter',
  'terms'    => array(30140, 30020, 30008, 29998, 29991, 21458,20197,11986,6614),
  'field'    => 'term_id',
  'operator' => 'NOT IN');
$query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you expect it to? `post__not_in` takes a list of *post* IDs, and returns posts that aren't in that list. `tax_query` queries posts based on which taxonomy terms they have.

Comment: Humm.... I am missing something........

Comment: Posts (which your `$query->set()` code addresses) are *not the same thing* as taxonomy terms (which the `$tax_query` code addresses). So it's only natural that your two code snippets do different things.

Answer (score 1):

Main problem with your code is that `tax_query` should be an array of queries, and not a single query.

```
$tax_query = array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'filter',
        'terms'    => array(30140, 30020, 30008, 29998, 29991, 21458,20197,11986,6614),
        'field'    => 'term_id',
        'operator' => 'NOT IN'
    )
);
$query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
```

Comment: Actually I did try: `$tax_query = array();` and (with square brackets) `$tax_query[] = array(
  'taxonomy' => 'filter',.....` but it wouldn't work either....wrong usage anyway!

Comment: In their example they're using the same IDs for posts and taxonomy terms. I believe their ultimate problem is misunderstanding what tax queries are for, not a syntax issue.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Yeah, I’ve noticed that. The syntax was one of the problem. The problem with ids is another one...